# \r\n shows as string in my text file

Tags: python, file, text, output, eol

I am a total noob to python.  But have lots of CLI experience on Cisco and such.  I have decided to make Python my 'go to' script tool.  And well, I have failed miserably my first try even stealing most of the code...

I am doing a ping of a list of hosts.  The purpose is to 1. Validate it is alive and 2. get the IP

The script I got online worked after a bit of tweaking for Version 3.4.

The display shows perfect like I want.  The file it writes is just one long line which appears to have the \r\n just written as part of the text.  This is the code and a sample of the screen dispay and the written file.

```
import sys
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import threading
import pexpect

hosts_file = open("hosts.txt","r")
lines = hosts_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "3",line],stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = ping.communicate()
    out = out.strip()
    error = error.strip()
    output = open("PingResults.txt",'a')
    output.write(str(out))
    output.write(str(error))
    print(out.decode('utf-8'))

    print(error.decode('utf-8'))
hosts_file.close()
```

**Screen is perfect**

```
Pinging HOST7.foo [10.180.43.209] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.180.43.209: bytes=32 time=81ms TTL=60
Reply from 10.180.43.209: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=60
Reply from 10.180.43.209: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=60
```

**Notepad++ reads as single line with visible \r\n (as do other editors**

```
b'Pinging host7.foo [10.180.43.11] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 10.18.43.11: bytes=32 time=555ms TTL=60\r\nReply from 10.18.43.11: bytes=32 time=140ms TTL=60\r\nReply from 10.180.43.11: bytes=32 time=139ms TTL=60\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 10.180.43.11:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 139ms, Maximum = 555ms, Average = 278ms'b''b'Pinging host9.foo [10.180.43.25] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from
```

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobie...you're my only hope...

Comment: From where does the input end up in Notepad++?`

Comment: I open the file pingresults.txt with notepad++

Comment: You're getting back bytes (that's what the `b'...'`) means so you've got to DECODE said bytes on input to your program and ENCODE them on the way out

Comment: Yes the strip is doing something but removing that doesn't help.  When I try the suggestion below I get an error I can't concat byte to string

Comment: OK my problem is the wite is writing everything in one line.  I thought it was looping as the for line in line went but it is not.  The text is written all as one line in the file so adding a os.linesep just sticks one at the very end of the line of text.  How do I break each line retuened by ping.communicate

Comment: Duplicate question even  answer here.

Error in answer though stderr.subprocess.PIPE is what it should be not Popen

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862111/python-console-and-text-output-from-ping-including-n-r

Answer (score 3):

I checked this code again on python 2.7 on ubuntu and it does work fine with the addition of the '\n' or os.linesep.

On python 3.2, subprocess.communicate returns a byte array.

using out.decode() should convert it to a string.

[python 2.7 below]

string.strip() removes end of line characters by default.

```
"Hello\n".strip()
```

returns

```
'Hello'
```

use

```
output.write(str(out + '\n'))
```

or

```
output.write(str(out + os.linesep))
```

[Python 3.X below]

```
output.write(out.decode() + os.linesep)
```

Comment: what if the OP wants the line separators to remain as-is?

Comment: trust me.  I'll take what I can get at the moment and then fix the format later... lol